# How to i get the last month values on the row?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

In powerbi
How do i go from this

[image]

to this

[image]

my logic is to use a new column insted of a measure, becouse its static values

```
#lastmonth = 

var lastmonth = format(DATEADD(X[Datum],-1,MONTH),"YYYY-MM-DD")
var rowmonth = FORMAT(X[Datum],"YYYY-MM-DD")

return  
IF(FORMAT(X,"YYYY-MM-DD") = lastmonth, X[Value])
```

i know this can't be becouse the date can never be the same as the lastmonth.. but i cant figuere it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Calculated Column, when you need data from other rows, then you will need to come out of the row context. This is can be done in a number of ways, here are a couple of examples:

Using `REMOVEFILTERS()`:

```
#lastmonth = 
  var prevMonth = DATEADD( X[Datum], -1, MONTH )
  RETURN
    CALCULATE(
      MIN(X[Value]),
      REMOVEFILTERS(),
      X[Description] = EARLIER(X[Description]) && X[Datum] = prevMonth
    )
```

Or an alternative:

```
#lastmonth = 
  var prevMonth = DATEADD( X[Datum], -1, MONTH )
  RETURN
    CALCULATE(
      MIN(X[Value]),
      ALLEXCEPT(X, X[Description]),
      X[Datum] = prevMonth
    )
```

Comment: You are amazing ♥ i tryed the last one and it works. It works even if i just show current month and it takes last month data. Now i just need to understand the code=D